# Page template no longer exists - metaboxes won't save

Tags: pages, metabox, templates

Ok, this is a weird one.

I first experienced this on an older theme that I developed - I assumed I had some buggy code in there somewhere, but couldn't figure it out even with the help of another couple developers.

Now I have a new theme, super lightweight - no buggy code, and it's happening again.

Here's the issue:

1. User has a theme installed with a custom page template - they save their page with this page template.
2. User switches themes, and the page template no longer exists - the "Page Template" option is no longer visible, as the new theme has no page templates.
3. When a user tries to save a options inside of a metabox (any metabox), the option simply reverts back to where it was before saving.

When the user creates a new, fresh page - the metabox saves just fine - no issues.

This only comes up when a page is looking for a page template that was installed that's no longer there.

I assume WordPress would have some sort of check in the core to see if the page template no longer exists - so what's going on?

In my old theme, I ended up using this code:

```
add_action('admin_init','pro_update_page_template_issue');
function pro_update_page_template_issue()
{
    global $post;

    if ( get_option('pro_updated_page_templates') == 'true' )
        return;

    add_option('pro_updated_page_templates','true');

    $args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'page'
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $page_template = $post->page_template;
        if( !locate_template($page_template) ) :
            update_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', 'default');
        endif;
    }
}
```

This works, but I would rather find the cause of this issue in my new theme.

Is this only happening to me? Can anyone else replicate the issue?

Thanks!